# JSF Partial Render from bean fails with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, jsf

I have a JSF Page with a outputpanel like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="panelToolbar" style="padding:0px !important">
   <div  id="bPrincipal" onclick="change_toolbar('Principal');">#{text['desktop.tabs.principal']}</div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

and with a remotCommand I call a bean method.
In the bean I execute this command

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("panelToolbar");
```

This run correct in Firefox and IExplorer 10.
But, in IExplorer 11 the panel disappear.

Anyone knows why it can happen?

Comment: Browser log? Errors?

Comment: No errors. Only disappear. It's very strange.

Comment: Post an entry into the primefaces forum.